# how to manipulate a DataFrame in which each value is a object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame in which each value is a object of custom class, say:

```
dc = {"c1":{"a1":CAppState(1,1), "a2":CAppState(2,4) }, "c2":{"a2":CAppState(2,5), "a3":CAppState(3,32)} }
df = pd.DataFrame(dc)
```

where CAppState is a class:

```
class CAppState(object):
    def __init__(self, nID, nValue):
        self.m_nID = nID
        self.m_nValue = nValue
```

I was wondering how could I conduct some common operations on this dataframe, like: cumsum() or sort according to CAppState.m_nValue ?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Operations like `cumsum` will operate on the values in the DataFrame.  So if you want to operate on your objects, you could implement `__add__` and the like so that they support adding, or you could make a new column containing the `m_nValue` values and use `cumsum` on that.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks, but what if I have multiple value in the custom class, how could I specify which value to be used in cumsum()?

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin way to do this.  You must create a Series from your objects and `cumsum` that.  This can be done fairly easily with `map`.  For instance:

```
df.c1.map(lambda x: x.m_nValue).cumsum()
```

You could also use `operator.attrgetter`:

```
df.c1.map(operator.attrgetter('m_nValue')).cumsum()
```